# Is there any Opensource Browser for touchscreen device?

Tags: browser, embedded, arm, embedded-linux, qtembedded

I need internet browser on my device which has 4.3 Inch screen with 480x272 resolution, I am using embedded Qt 4.6.2 on embedded linux. Micro-controller has ARM9 with 450 Mhz.

Requirements for browser are

- Touch Screen Support, Panning ( No Scroll bars)
- Single touch Zooming ( No Multi Touch Available).
- Fit to screen width support ( No Horizontal Scrolling).
- Acid 3 Standard Compliable.
- Page loading should be like, display all visible text first 
          and then load and show Images Gradually.

Is there any opensource browser which is near to this requirements.

I found following browsers which have touch screen support.

- [Firefox Mobile](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/mobile/)
- [Maemo MicroB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroB) ( Can any one please tell me where can I found source of this one).

Comment: My guess would be 'no'. In any case - wrong site for this question.

Comment: Why wrong site, Its related to programming. I want to port browser and make necessary changes to it.

Answer (score 2):

> Maemo MicroB ( Can any one please tell
>   me where can I found source of this
>   one).

If it helps: MicroB source package is [here](http://maemo.org/packages/source/view/fremantle_sdk_free_source/microb-engine/20091230-1.9.2-6.16+0m5/).

As a user of this browser I can say that it is very touch-friendly. Can't confirm support of all the features you've listed though.

Answer (score 1):

How about using dillo? [Dillo](http://www.dillo.org/)
or how about the [QT/Webkit](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtwebkit.html) since you are already using QT? You could also look at [Midori](http://www.twotoasts.de/index.php?/pages/midori_summary.html) but I have never used it. For the touch sensor part this depends on your touch drivers. Perhaps run a window manager.

Comment: All these browsers are not touch screen friendly and not small screen friendly ( Zoom Functionality is not supported.)